# Items disappear when editing inside an Angular ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs

I have an array of items that each display as a directive inside an ng-repeat like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.data | filter:ctrl.query"  class="ubi-box container-fluid">
  <user-item item="item" . . .></user-item>
</div>
```

As you can see, there is a filter on the ng-repeat. Inside the directives, users can edit items inside forms that show when the user clicks on one of the items.

Trouble occurs when the user edits a field that affects the filter. If the user has found the item using the filter (ctrl.query), and if the edited text means the item no longer matches the filter, that item suddenly vanishes before the user can hit save or anything. Poof!

What is the most elegant solution? I don't want to turn the filter off when editing commences, because then all the items will reappear. I want the filter to still work, but I want the item being edited to keep showing even if it would be filtered out.

Do I set an "isOpen" flag in each item, and add an "or isOpen" clause to the filter? Adding flags like that always feels kludgy to me, and I'm not even sure how to do that in the filter syntax.

Do I add an "or isFormVisible" clause to the filter? That might be neater, but again, how do I even do that in the ngRepeat filter syntax?

Thoughts?

Thanks in advance

John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be more elegant solutions out there, but I would probably follow the example from the Angular documentation.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#binding-to-form-and-control-state

When editing commences, copy the item being edited to a new object that populates the edit controls (the view controls behind the scenes are still the master object).  Once you save, you copy the updated object into the master object which will at that point revert back to the view mode and it'll be hidden by the filter.

Something along these lines:

```
  $scope.edit = function (item){
    $scope.editItem = angular.copy(item);
  }

  $scope.saveTo = function(item){
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++){
      if ($scope.items[i].id === item.id){
        $scope.items[i] = angular.copy($scope.editItem);
        break;
      }
    }

    $scope.editItem = {};
  }
```

I compare the ID in the item being edited to the ids of each item in the list to ensure only one can be ng-if'd at a time.  Here's a sample [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Tu0RPO?p=preview).

---

Update: Here's another [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/B147r0?p=preview) that uses a different query filter and all you do is set a flag when you go into edit mode to an id.  Similar to the one before, but none of the master object code.  If you already have an edit mode, this seems like it should be pretty quick to apply.

Comment: That's the answer I'm afraid of, because that's a lot of work rewriting a lot of code :( I was hoping to just tweak the filter, maybe (now that I read more) with a function. But I fear you may be right. I have used that pattern elsewhere in my app, so I know it well enough. Thanks.

Comment: @John I gave it another spin.

Comment: I started working on implementing your first answer, and it's not all that hard to implement, as it happens, due to the way I structured my directives. It's no harder than your second answer: just a few lines of code. (I was already using the copy-the-model pattern for the form reset function, so it was just a matter of inverting it for form save, and passing the copy to the form directive.) So which one is the more solid approach, do you think? That first copy-the-model pattern is from the docs, so maybe I should go with that? Thanks a million.

Comment: @John I think that depends on your code and your intentions.  There are advantages you can get by not automatically updating your main model.  For instance, if that's the model you save, you wouldn't be able to accidentally post & persist your model being edited before you actually want to because you haven't updated the original.  I think the original would actually be my preferred.  Also, if I was helpful to you, mind throwing me at least an upvote? :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `ng-model-options` along with `$render` option, here is a working example : **http://plnkr.co/edit/IFpXBYeJx1wrbKhhzMZg?p=preview**

```
  <form name="userForm">
    <label>Name:
      <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="name" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'click' }" />
    </label>
    <button ng-click="userForm.userName.$render();">Update Now</button>
    <br />
  </form>
```

Comment: Won't updateOn:'click' just delay the update till the user clicks on something? Wouldn't I need updateOn:'submit'? The trouble with that would be, my form has a lot of live validation, such as testing for valid email addresses, and if I delay model updates the validations don't run at the right time.

Comment: I havent personally tried this, but I believe you are looking for the form.username.$error is there is an error, so that shouldnt matter if your modal is already updated or not, can you give that a try